# Merge Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, merge

Hi i want to merge some dictionatries.

```
dic=
 {
 'a' : {'x':1,'y':1,'z':1},
 'b' : {'q':1,'w':1,'z':1},
 'c' : {'x':1,'f':1,'z':1},
 'd' : {'x':1,'m':1,'r':1}
  }
```

The result should look like this [x,y,z,q,w,f,m,r] .

Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Please define exactly how the result should look like.

Comment: What does your script output? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: it seems he needs only the keys of the inner dictionaries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
answer = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dic.itervalues())))
```

If you'd like to ignore certain keys:

```
blacklist = set('a b'.split())
answer = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v for k,v in dic.iteritems if k not in blacklist)))
```

Comment: Beautiful. First nice use of "from_iterable" I see.

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to get this list without for example the dictonary "a"?

Comment: @SiMon: Check ou the update

Answer (score 4):

```
s = set()
for v in dic.values():
    s = s.union(v.keys())
```

Comment: shouldn't it be union?

Comment: (+1) I've taken the liberty of fixing the method name (`intersection` -> `union`).

Answer (score 4):

If order doesn't matter:

```
>>> dic = {'a': {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}, 'c': {'x': 1, 'z': 1, 'f': 1}, 'b': {'q': 1, 'z': 1, 'w': 1}, 'd': {'x': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 1}}
>>> set().union(*dic.values())
set(['q', 'r', 'w', 'f', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'm'])
```

If something like order does matter, we could use sorted order and first appearance:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(v for k in sorted(dic) for v in sorted(dic[k])).keys()
['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 'f', 'm', 'r']
```

Comment: (+1) Beautiful (and IMO the order cannot matter since the original dictionaries have no defined ordering to start with).

Comment: Yep, much simpler to pass everything to a single `union` call than to `reduce` over N-1 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
result = set()
for subdic in dic.values():
  result |= set(subdic.keys())
print result
```

?

Note that this does not preserve the ordering of keys, but then dictionary keys have no defined ordering to start with...

Comment: Y exactly thanks a lot. No order needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of a distinct keys of inner lists:

```
import collections    

    dic = {
     'a' : {'x':1,'y':1,'z':1},
     'b' : {'q':1,'w':1,'z':1},
     'c' : {'x':1,'f':1,'z':1},
     'd' : {'x':1,'m':1,'r':1}
      }

    a = collections.Counter([v for d in dic.values() for v in d])
    l = a.keys()
```